# TN visa processing for USA

Tags: usa, visa, canadian-citizens, tn-visa

Am currently Canadian citizen working as an employee for a software company(registered in Canada).

This software company makes inventory management software for businesses that sell cannabis(marijuana).

In future, I would like to work in USA, through TN visa.

Would that be an issue to apply for TN visa? After working for cannabis related business software company

Comment: While cannabis (and trade in cannabis) is permitted by several US states, it is prohibited in others. The federal government uniformly prohibits cannabis and trade therein, and the federal government is the government that will rule on your TN visa application. The conflicts between state and federal law are ongoing and unresolved. I don't know the answer to your question...but I'm an attorney and I can easily imagine that a TN visa application will be denied if the words "cannabis" or "marijuana" appears in the application, or perhaps even in your résumé.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica this company has a main headquarter in california and has one branch in Vancouver,Canada

Comment: In addition to what DavidSupportsMonica said, I would note that being a controlled substance trafficker, or aiding, abetting, assisting, conspiring with, or colluding with controlled substance trafficking, leads to a lifetime ban on entry to the US under INA 212(a)(2)(C). The work you are describing may be considered to be assisting or conspiring with controlled substance trafficking, since cannabis is a controlled substance.

Comment: @user102008 So, this looks like a serious matter to me

Comment: It could indeed be a serious matter. The federal government obviously tolerates some state-approved cannabis business, but it (the federal government) isn't required to do so. It may act differently in the future, even as to currently-tolerated businesses, and might well say "no" when given a non-public chance to do so...as in a visa application. If you wish to proceed, I would consult with an attorney in the US who's versed in both US immigration and US cannabis issues before you take action.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but USCIS did clarify in 2019 that they do still consider marijuana to be an illegal drug as far as establishing Good Moral Character for naturalization (https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/policy-manual-updates/20190419-ControlledSubstanceViolations.pdf), so as @DavidSupportsMonica explains, USCIS definitely does still explicitly consider marijuana to be illegal, regardless of its legal status in various states/countries. As he notes, they may act differently with regards to you case, however.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain the company , where I work, the name is "treez"(registered in Canada). Currently working for this company in Canada. This company head quarter is in California. How come US federal government registered this company? If marijuana is illegal

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica "The federal government obviously tolerates ... but ... isn't required to do so": furthermore, the federal government can refuse entry to foreigners based on activities that US citizens are allowed to do.  For example, Canadians have been refused entry for the purpose of participating in political protests (though I doubt this has been tested in court), and foreigners are banned by law from entering the US if they have certain political affiliations even though once they enter the US their right to maintain these affiliations would be protected by the first amendment.

Comment: For a TN, you need to be a _professional_ as defined in the statute and the treaty. My TNs were always based on my Canadian engineering degree. The easiest way to get a TN is to present yourself at the border with proof of your professional standing (as described in the treaty), a letter from your employer, and the fee. The wording of the letter is key. It must be a temporary and the job must require your professional skills. In all my TNs, I was never asked detailed questions about my employer's business. Caveat, they were all pre-9/11.

Comment: If your employer has an established business in the US, consider getting an L1 status instead